# 4 players rolling a dice game

Tags: probability

THIS QUESTION WAS ASKED PREVIOUSLY HERE

[Best number to choose in a betting game](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4246100/best-number-to-choose-in-a-betting-game)

I just don't understand the solution given. Can someone please break it down more carefully?

Assume 3 players are rolling a 50-sided dice. And as the 4-th player, you can choose an integer 1≤≤50. Now after the rolling, the players with the highest/lowest numbers, as well as the two middle ones, team up. The team with the greater sum of the rolls pays the the team with the lower sum the difference of their sums. For example, suppose the rollings are 48,50,2,10, then the team 48,10 need to pay 50,2 an amount of 6.

Which  do you pick to maximize your expected value, and what expected value is it?

Comment: Please link to the previous question so we can check the solution you didn't understand.

Comment: @GrahamKemp edited